# Scope inconsistencies with coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I am a beginner with coffeescript and I can't really understand the scoping. I have read that coffee always redefines variables so that it is impossible to leak anything. But look at the following code :

```
b = 2

bla = () ->
  a = 1
  b = 2
  null

a = 1
```

which compiles to

```
(function() {
  var a, b, bla;

  b = 2;

  bla = function() {
    var a;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    return null;
  };

  a = 1;

}).call(this);
```

So basically while exactly the same operations, in the same scopes, happen to `a` and `b`, the result is very different. `b` leaks outside of the `bla` function, while `a` doesn't. Is it a bug or maybe a feature I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a designed behavior of CoffeeScript.

See [**Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope) section of CoffeeScript docs for more info:

> Notice how all of the variable declarations have been pushed up to the
>   top of the closest scope, the first time they appear.

In case of CofeeScript, it's a correct behavior, because it allows you to use upper-level variables, visible in your current lexical scope.

The thing that CoffeeScript lacks is a way to forcibly re-declare variable.

Comment: it is strange, it is practical, and it is common practice—python does it roughly this way, too. it does sometimes bite people. i tend to think it's basically not such a bad idea, but what is missing is a syntactic quick fix that lets you refer to a variable `a` that lives explicitly in 'this' scope, the next surrounding one, the module namespace, or the global namespace. python has `nonlocal` and `global` declarations, but i find those rather confusing in themselves.